# Disable/Enable button based on which control has focus

Tags: textbox, vb6, focus

What I'm trying to do here is loop through the different controls and if any of the controls got focus to disable a button. This is a loop that I used for another task, so I'm kinda basing it off of this...

```
Dim cControl As Control

For Each cControl In Me.controls
    If Not cControl.Container Is framClient Then
        If Mid(cControl.Name, 1, 3) = "txt" Or Mid(cControl.Name, 1, 3) =  "msk" Or Mid(cControl.Name, 1, 3) = "cbo" Then
       'WHAT I'm trying to do here is
       'if cControl.gotfocus then
           'cmdExit.enabled=false  
       'end if ' but it barks at me   
       'cControl.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If
Next
```

I didn't make these text boxes in an array and I do not want to go through each text box to see if got focus and do whatever. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vb6 only one control can have focus: the [ActiveControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267252(v=vs.60).aspx), so there's no point in looping and asking if the control has focus.

If you need to do something based on whether a certain control with a particular name has focus you could do this:

```
cmdExit.Enabled = (Me.ActiveControl.Name = "MyTextBox")
```

If you need to do it based on whether *any* TextBox has focus:

```
If TypeOf Me.ActiveControl Is TextBox Then
  cmdExit.Enabled = false
Else
  cmdExit.Enabled = true
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead with Subclassing of text boxes as suggested in [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435316/add-an-event-handler-to-each-control-on-a-form-at-runtime-vb6).

As the post suggests, you have to do this exercise for every form where you have this requirement. I think, from your post that you have to do it only for one form.